# ElasticSearch: Mapping MultiLineString to Nest Object in .Net

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm trying to obtain certain objects in .Net from our ElasticSearch database. In general, the attribute mapping works well, but I can't obtain my geometries, being them MultiLineStrings.

Here's the part of the mapping from ES:

```
      (...)
      "geometry" : {
        "type" : "geo_shape",
        "tree" : "quadtree"
      }
      (...)
```

Here's one result of this document:

```
"geometry" : {
  "type" : "MultiLineString",
  "coordinates" : [
    [
      [
        -0.3024731508,
        39.6154086637
      ],
      [
        -0.3024750709,
        39.6154090056
      ]
    ]
  ]
},
```

and in .Net:

```
    [PropertyName("geometry")]
    public MultiLineStringGeoShape Geometry { get; set; } //Where MultiLineStringGeoShape is in Nest namespace
```

But, when I try to obtain this object, Geometry is always null. I have tried to modify Geometry's type to object, and it maps correctly being the object a Nest's JObject that I can't convert or deserialize to MultiLineStringGeoShape.
All other properties map correctly.

We're using ElasticSearch 6.2.4 and Nest 6.2.0.

Did I miss anything?
Thanks.

Comment: What version of NEST are you using, and what version of Elasticsearch are you running against?

Comment: @RussCam Sorry, forgot to write it. Edited the question to add ES and Nest versions.